# html video tag not working on internet explorer

Tags: html5-video, internet-explorer-11

I am using a video background for my website. Which runs fine on all browser on local host. But when I upload it to ipage server, it does not run on IE11. Here is my code.

```
<video autoplay loop muted class="visible-lg visible-md">
 <source src="video/sh.mp4" type='video/mp4" codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'>
 <source src="video/shanonaction.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

First check your IE version. If it is lower than 9, you need to use the Flash player. You can also used `embed` in Internet Explorer 8 or lower.

Like this:

```
<pre>
    <video id="Video1" controls width="100%" height="auto" poster="pic.png">
        <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4;' />                                                
        <embed src="video.mp4" wmode="opaque">                                                   
            <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />                                     
        </embed>
    </video>
</pre>
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This took me a really long time to figure out. No one seemed to know.

The issue is the pixel size of the video.

For some odd reason. Internet Explorer 11 will simply ignore any video whose height is more than around 1000 pixels. so a 1080p html 5 video will not load, but a 720p will.

Comment: what is your implementation? can you please share your code?